# System independent pseudo number generator

Tags: java, android, ios, random

I am looking for an algorithm, which generates random numbers based on a seed. I do know that there are some system-wide solutions for that, but I need one which generates the same numbers in iOS and Android/Java.

Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). They give good results and are very easy to implement in any language.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rand = new Random(seed);
```

Maybe you are looking for the Random object in java?

Edit: Didn't see the bit about iOS. That will satisfy all platforms which use java.

Comment: that's the thing. I need the same numbers in iOS ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could grab a copy of [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html).  It has implementations available in both Java and C (which will work in Objective-C) that produce identical results given identical initialization. Also, MT is statistically superior to LCGs.